# Изменение параметра из адаптера RecyclerView kotlin

Tags: android, массивы, kotlin

не понимаю как сделать то что необходимо, помогите пожалуйста или скажите про что читать. 
Необходимо вывести список элементов (от 1 до 100) через recycler.

Вот MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fifth)
    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
    val recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
    for (i in 1..100){
    recyclerAdapter.value.add(i) //Здесь неправильно
    }
  }
}
```

Вот адаптер:

```
class RecyclerAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(){

val value = ArrayList<Int>()

fun setValue(number:List<Int>){
    value.clear()
    value.addAll(number)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
...
```

Нужно чтоб хранилище заполнялось пришедшими в массиве элементами, но я не понимаю как мне получить number, чтобы его уже поместить в цикл для наполнения.
Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Удалось получить то что хотел

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val numberList = ArrayList<Int>()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fifth)
    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
    val recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
    for (i in 1..100){
        numberList.add(i)
        recyclerAdapter.setValue(numberList)
    }
}
```

Comment: recyclerAdapter.setValue(numberList) нужно вынести из цикла по хорошему